# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clientes.clientes_id'

Tags: php, sql, laravel, relation

I'm new to the programming world, I'm studying laravel on my own, and I got this error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clientes.clientes_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `clientes` where `clientes`.`clientes_id` = 1 and `clientes`.`clientes_id` is not null) (View: /shared/httpd/laravel_8_crud/resources/views/pedidos/index.blade.php)

Could someone help me with the case?

My goal is to display the customer's name recorded in the database with this relationship.

Thanks in advance.

Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePedidosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pedidos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->enum('status',['aberto', 'pago', 'cancelado',]);
            $table->bigInteger('clientes_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('clientes_id')->references('id')->on('clientes')->onCascade('delete');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pedidos');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pedido extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'pedidos';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'status',
        'clientes_id',
        'created_at'
    ];

    public function clientes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cliente::class, 'clientes_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Pedido;
use App\Models\Cliente;

class PedidosController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * mostrar conteudo no index
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $pedidos = Pedido::orderBy('id','asc')->paginate(10);

        return view('pedidos.index', compact('pedidos'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Mostra o form para criar um novo pedido.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $clientes = Cliente::all();
        return view('pedidos.create', compact('clientes'));
    }

    /**
     * armazena um novo pedido pra enviar ao BD
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'status' => 'required',
            'clientes_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        Pedido::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('pedidos.index')
            ->with('success', 'Pedido cadastrado com sucesso');
    }

    /**
     * Exibe um pedido
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Pedido  $pedido
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Pedido $pedido)
    {
        return view('pedidos.show', compact('pedido'));
    }

    /**
     * Exibe um pedido para edição
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Pedido  $pedido
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Pedido $pedido)
    {
        return view('pedidos.edit', compact('pedido'));
    }
    /**
     * Atualiza um pedido no BD
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Pedido  $pedido
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Pedido $pedido)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'status' => 'required',
        ]);
        $pedido->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('pedidos.index')
            ->with('success', 'Pedido atualizado com sucesso');
    }
    /**
     * Remove um pedido do BD
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Pedido  $pedido
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Pedido $pedido)
    {
        $pedido->delete();

        return redirect()->route('pedidos.index')
            ->with('success', 'Pedido deletado com sucesso');
    }
}
```

Index

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
</br>
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md ">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Cadastro de Pedidos</h2>
            </div>
            </br>
            @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <p>{{ $message }}</p>
            </div>
            @endif

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Nº</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
                        <th scope="col">Status</th>
                        <th scope="col">Data de criação</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ação</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($pedidos as $pedido)
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">{{ $pedido->id }}</td>
                        <td scope="row">{{ $pedido->clientes }}</td> //This line error if $pedido->cliente_id  bring me the ID, but I would like to display the name
                        <td scope="row">{{ $pedido->status }}</td>
                        <td scope="row">{{ date_format($pedido->created_at, 'd-m-Y H:i:s') }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="{{ route('pedidos.destroy', $pedido->id) }}" method="POST">
                                <a href="{{ route('pedidos.show', $pedido->id) }}" title="Visualizar">
                                    <i class="fas fa-eye text-success fa-lg"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="{{ route('pedidos.edit', $pedido->id) }}" title="Editar">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                                </a>
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button type="submit" title="Deletar" style="border: none; background-color:transparent;">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger"></i>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('pedidos.create') }}" title="Adicionar um Pedido"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{!! $pedidos->links() !!}

@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u need to define a belongs to relation in this model
since clinetes_id is a foreign key in pedido. so pedido is belonges to
clientes

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Pedido extends Model
    {
    
        protected $table = 'pedidos';
        public $timestamps = true;
    
        protected $fillable = [
            'status',
            'clientes_id',
            'created_at'
        ];
    
        public function clientes()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class, 'clientes_id');
        }
    }
```

index.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
</br>
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md ">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Cadastro de Pedidos</h2>
            </div>
            </br>
            @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <p>{{ $message }}</p>
            </div>
            @endif

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Nº</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
                        <th scope="col">Status</th>
                        <th scope="col">Data de criação</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ação</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($pedidos as $pedido)
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">{{ $pedido->id }}</td>
                        <td scope="row">{{ $pedido->clientes->name }}</td> 
                        <td scope="row">{{ $pedido->status }}</td>
                        <td scope="row">{{ date_format($pedido->created_at, 'd-m-Y H:i:s') }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="{{ route('pedidos.destroy', $pedido->id) }}" method="POST">
                                <a href="{{ route('pedidos.show', $pedido->id) }}" title="Visualizar">
                                    <i class="fas fa-eye text-success fa-lg"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="{{ route('pedidos.edit', $pedido->id) }}" title="Editar">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                                </a>
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button type="submit" title="Deletar" style="border: none; background-color:transparent;">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger"></i>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('pedidos.create') }}" title="Adicionar um Pedido"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{!! $pedidos->links() !!}

@endsection
```